# SQL CLR in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-clr

Can we call SQL CLR in MySQL Server using User Define Function?

I want to create trigger in mysql. It will call user define function and this UDF will update the table in SQL Server.

Comment: Since when does MySQL have a CLR (.NET runtime)?

Comment: A UDF library with functions to interact with the operating system. These functions allow you to interact with the execution environment in which MySQL runs.  I am trying to call external dll in mysql. Please go through this article.http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.in/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.  Or no you can't.  It doesn't really matter.  If you think about how DBMS1 is going to have to deal with a commit and/or rollback after it has, via your UDF function in which you have hidden an update to another, external, DBMS2, then you should realize that this is a very bad idea no matter how you toss or turn it, because somwewhere somehow it is going to happen that an update transaction has gone non-ACID-compliant.